# Understanding External Class Folder

Tags: java, classpath, eclipse-classpath

Whilst learning to develop servlets I added `C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat8\lib\servlet-api.jar` to my J2EE project's build path to get the servlets to work. All fine:

[image]

I then decided to instead add the entire folder `C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat8\lib` as an "External Class Folder" and suddenly I'm back to "javax.servlet cannot be resolved".

[image]

This seems to make no sense especially when compared to how eclipse adds the Tomcat library - it looks almost identical:

[[image: [3]]

I guess the questions are:

1. What is wrong with my including an entire folder as a "library"?
2. How would one properly add a folder so that it appears as a proper library as in the "Apache Tomcat v8.0" library eclipse adds via wizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it seems adding an external class folder means "adding a folder containing class files" and not, as one might hope, "adding a folder containing .jar files containing class files". Thus eclipse, finding no class files in my tomcat/lib folder fails to see the class files inside servlet-api.jar.

As for my 2nd question it's possible to create "User Libraries" as follows:

1. Window -> Preferences
2. Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries
3. Click New... button and enter a name
4. Click the new library and then "Add External JARs..."
5. Browse to tomcat/lib and add all .jar files

To reference this library:

1. Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Add Library... button
3. Choose "User Library"
4. Choose your library

Answer (score 1):

Class-Folders are folders with compiled classes not folder with libs.
You could use the User-Library feature of eclipse but in generell you have to add every jar by hand.

Comment: Thanks Henningy, I found the explanation in parallel to you and have described it below in case it helps other noobs like me.